# Key press is not being recognised by python's 'pygame.key.get_pressed()' module

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a function where if a key is pressed, variables are changed. This will be put into a class that moves a sprite on a screen. The while loop is broken when the key is released. However, nothing happens. The while loop is running and I get no error. Does anyone know why this might be happening? I am not sure if I am using the function `pygame.key.get_pressed()` correctly.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
def move():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.QUIT()
                sys.exit()
    while True:
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
            print("something happens")
        #runs this, but when up arrow key is pressed does nothing
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            False

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((512,384))
move()          
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: `get_pressed()` doesn't work if you don't execute `pygame.event.get()` - but you execute `pygame.event.get()` only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_pressed()` returns list with information about pressed keys but this list is updated by `pygame.event.get()` and other event functions so you have to execute `pygame.event.get()` all the time. And this is why we do it in `while-loop`

```
import pygame   

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((512,384))

while True:

    # get events and (somewhere in background) update list
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    # get current list.
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
        print("UP")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
def move():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.QUIT()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                print("up pressed")

            # etc.

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                print("up released")

            # etc.
```

For more key names you can go to the [Pygame Key Docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html)

Comment: This doesn't seem to yield a different result - there is still no printed statement. However I don't get an error?

Comment: I had removed my while loop, it works now. Thank you!